# Is there a notification when ASP.NET Web API completes sending to the client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web API to stream large files to clients, but I'd like to log if the download was successful or not. That is, if the server sent the entire content of the file.

Is there some way to get a a callback or event when the `HttpResponseMessage` completes sending data?

Perhaps something like this:

```
var stream = GetMyStream();
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");    
// This doesn't exist, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do.
response.OnComplete(context =>
{
    if (context.Success)
        Log.Info("File downloaded successfully.");
    else
        Log.Warn("File download was terminated by client.");
});
```

Comment: Wow, precisely and concisely what I want to do today, 8 year later!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I've now tested this using a real connection (via fiddler).

I inherited `StreamContent` and added my own `OnComplete` action which checks for an exception:

```
public class StreamContentWithCompletion : StreamContent
{
    public StreamContentWithCompletion(Stream stream) : base (stream) { }
    public StreamContentWithCompletion(Stream stream, Action<Exception> onComplete) : base(stream) 
    { 
        this.OnComplete = onComplete; 
    }

    public Action<Exception> OnComplete { get; set; }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        var t = base.SerializeToStreamAsync(stream, context);
        t.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            if (this.OnComplete != null)
            {
                // The task will be in a faulted state if something went wrong. 
                // I observed the following exception when I aborted the fiddler session: 
                // 'System.Web.HttpException (0x800704CD): The remote host closed the connection.'
                if (x.IsFaulted)
                    this.OnComplete(x.Exception.GetBaseException());
                else
                    this.OnComplete(null);
            }
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Then I use it like so:

```
var stream = GetMyStream();
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContentWithCompletion(stream, ex =>
{
    if (ex == null)
        Log.Info("File downloaded successfully.");
    else
        Log.Warn("File download was terminated by client.");
});
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");    
return response;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is direct signaling that all is ok, but you can use a trick to find out that the connection is exist just before you end it up, and right after you fully send the file.

For example the `Response.IsClientConnected` is return true if the client is still connected, so you can check something like:

```
// send the file, make a flush
Response.Flush();
// and now the file is fully sended check if the client is still connected
if(Response.IsClientConnected)
{
  // log that all looks ok until the last byte.
}
else
{
  // the client is not connected, so maybe have lost some data
}

// and now close the connection.
Response.End();
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work for me when I'm in `ApiController` action methods. As far as I know, nothing happens until I return the `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: @ligos Can you make a test ? - the other that I like to say you is, can you write your data inside a loop in small parts with a buffer, and check if the final download is the same as the file size ?

Comment: Yep, I'll run a test tomorrow. Oh, and the client side will have an SHA256 hash of the file available anyway, so I'm got the file integrity covered.

Comment: I've stopped using `IsClientConnected` because of a) threading issues - HttpContext isn't available on the async thread used to stream the content and b) the async task provides an exception if there is a failure. (Note, once I worked around the threading issue, IsClientConnected is false on an error).

Comment: @ligos Ok, thank you for the feedback, I say that I leave it as answer and not delete it for the reference and the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> if the server sent the entire content of the file

Actually there is nothing to do :)

This might sound very simplistic but you will know if an exception is raised - if you care about server delivering and not client cancelling halfway. `IsClientConnected` is based on ASP.NET `HttpResponse` not the  WebApi.

Comment: I"m going to run some tests tomorrow, but do you have a reference to an exception being thrown on MSDN?

Comment: @ligos depends what goes wrong. What do you expect to go wrong? Network error?

Comment: Client side internet drop out would be the main thing. Something that, from the server point of view, looks like a connection being dropped. I'll try to simulate such a thing with fiddler.

Comment: You were correct, there is a faulted tasks in my version of `StreamContent.SerializeToStreamAsync` which I've used to signal an error. However, this exception isn't thrown in the usual Web API world (as far as I can tell).